# Lists: Centering a custom bullet with first line of text

Tags: css

possibly (hopefully) a simple question:

I'm using a png as a bullet in an unordered list using code found on here :

```
li {
background:url(../images/bullet.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
list-style:none;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

The only variation I've made to this is to set the vertical background position to 50% so that the bullet stays centred regardless of the size of text etc (and/or to avoid the need for different sized bullet pngs depending on text size).

The only problem with this is that if the text in the list moves onto a second line, the bullet centres with the two-line width of text (in other words the bullet sits somewhere near the space between the two lines).

Is it possible to keep the bullet centered with the font height, but of the first line only ?

Cheers in advance for any tips.

Comment: "set the vertical background position to 50%" - can you show the code that sets this?

Comment: Just by changing the 0 0 to 0 50%

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try setting a relative line-height to the  element and use pseudo element to hold the bullet. This works with any text size:

```
ul {
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li {
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    margin-top: .2em;
    line-height: inherit;
    background:url(../images/bullet.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, will have a look at this when I get back home.

Comment: based on the fiddle of `SW4` and the idea of using `:before` pseudo-element of `lulian Anghel`, I edited the fiddle with finer result here http://jsfiddle.net/XMWa6/2/ , with this edited version, the bullet will have size scaled according to the font size, we also have to tweak it a little with transform.

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/XMWa6/)

Seems to work here:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    background:url(http://drjohnart.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/bullet-point.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left:20px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, when I said about the text moving onto a second line, I should have said wrapping onto a second line - not text with breaks in. (The list is in a fluid container so, depending on the size of the browser, sometimes the text is on just one line, when smaller it wraps onto a second line).